# Measure the string from an angular model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have a input and a span like this:

```
<input type="password" name="account_password" placeholder="Enter your new password" autocomplete="off" ng-model="res.account.new_password" required="" ng-minlength="res.minlength" class="form-control" />
                        <span ng-show="(res.account.new_password).length == res.minlength" class="text-danger">Should be at least 6 characters long</span><br>
```

In the angular controller I have a variable:                             `vm.minlength = 6;`
The ng-minlength directive works but I try to display an error message for the user too:

```
<span ng-show="(res.account.new_password).length == res.minlength" class="text-danger">Should be at least 6 characters long</span><br>
```

But it doesn't work. After the first letter I type the error message dissapears.

`res` is the alias for my controller in case you were wondering (I am using `vm` to declare the variables in my angular controller). Any help is welcomed! Thank you for your time!

After chaging `==` to `<` the span doesn't get displayed at all!

Comment: According to your message, your span's ng-show should be `ng-show="(res.account.new_password).length < res.minlength"`

Comment: In addition to the answers below I'd also suggest you take a look at `ngMessages` - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your alert will be displayed only if your password is **exactly** 6 chars, not 6 and less...

If you want a min length, then I think you should change your condition from `==` to `<`:

```
<span ng-show="(res.account.new_password).length < res.minlength" class="text-danger">Should be at least 6 characters long</span><br>
```

Here is a **[demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/pohfm83e/)**.

---

*PS: In your controller you defined `vm.minlength`, I guess it should be `res.minlength`.*

Comment: Thank you I overlooked it :( but apparently now it doesn't get displayed at all

Comment: I edited my answer to add a Fiddle example. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Ok, I think your error is that your defined `vm.minlength`, change it to `res.minlength`.